# Keep alive does not respond with ACK if interval more than 5 minutes

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am using the **SetKeepAlive** method with 10 minutes interval and I get the following traces without ACK:

- TCP:[Keep alive]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=20100, DstPort=13529, PayloadLen=1,
- TCP:[Keep alive]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=20100, DstPort=13529, PayloadLen=1,
- TCP:[Keep alive]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=20100, DstPort=13529, PayloadLen=1,

But if I change to 5 minutes, I get the ACKs

- TCP:[Keep alive]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=20100, DstPort=15067, PayloadLen=1,
- TCP:[**Keep alive ack**]Flags=...A...., SrcPort=15067, DstPort=20100, PayloadLen=0,

I am using a TcpClient socket with ReceiveTimeout = 0 and a SslStream with ReadTimeout = Timeout.Infinite

### Q1) Any suggestion on how to set the keep alives for more than 5 minutes and get ACK from the other side?

### Q2) Is it require to set Keep-Alives both ends? If yes do the interval need to match?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer: At home router (XFINITY modem) needs traffic to maintain the route and therefore the 5 minute worked but not 10. As soon as I took the environment to the office, I was able to sustain a connected socket for long periods.

The problem was not in the **TcpClient** or in the **SetKeepAlive** function but in the network infrastructure.

Only want to add to this post that I only needed to use:

```
sock.IOControl(IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, result);
```

This other call made NO different:

```
Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true)
```